# Chef - ERROR: RuntimeError: Please set EDITOR environment variable

Tags: chef-infra

I've installed successfully chef on my workstation but when i am trying to create a role using the following command

```
knife role create startmeup
```

I get

> ERROR: RuntimeError: Please set EDITOR environment variable

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 45):

You have to define `EDITOR` as environment variable.

Try

```
export EDITOR=$(which vi)
```

To persist this, add it to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: How do I set the Editor in Windows?

Comment: You can do it the same way - at least as long as your using `msysgit`. Open the Git Bash and execute a `ls .bash*` to see, if one of the files `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` exist. Then edit (or create a new one) and place that line there.

Comment: If you're not using the Git Bash, please provide more info.

Comment: On Windows, I had to specify the full path, using escaped 8.3 notation, e.g. knife[:editor] = "C:\\Progra~2\\Notepa~1\\Notepad++.exe".  See https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4503

Comment: You can also configure it in single quotes and double quotes. That is: `knife[:editor] = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"'` works.

Comment: I had some trouble getting the right syntax in Ubuntu. `export EDITOR="/usr/bin/nano"` worked for me.

Answer (score 28):

In your knife.rb file (~/.chef/knife.rb) add the following line for notepad++ :

```
knife[:editor] = "C:\\progra~2\\notepa~1\\notepad++.exe -nosession -multiInst"
```

or if you just want to use notepad

```
knife[:editor] = "notepad"
```

or emacs for GNU

```
knife[:editor] = "emacs"
```

Answer (score 5):

I use something like this:

```
knife role create startmeup -e vi
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set it for that session, the command

```
set EDITOR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

works.

Answer (score 3):

There're a few ways to deal with the problem.

1. set the **environment variable $EDITOR**. You can export it by `export EDITOR=vim` in shell, or put this line in files like **.bashrc**;
2. pass the **option `-e vim`** (namely `--editor vim`)to the `knife` command. For example, you can do it like this:

   `knife role create startmeup -e vim`
3. modify **~/.chef/knife.rb** by add this line:

   `knife[:editor] = "vim"`

Answer (score 2):

Just set your editor and it will work. In my case I use vim editor that's why my command was as follows:

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

Comment: This answer was given a couple days ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
export EDITOR=vi
```

In my case it worked.but for ubuntu14.o version vi editor backspace is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this entry to the knife config file worked for me

```
knife[:editor] = "Notepad"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have notepad++ installed in your machine :

```
knife environment create startmeup -e notepad++
```

Answer (score 0):

Knife prioritizes knife.rb over the environment variable.

It seems knife will default to vim (on my system, anyway) if no config is provided, so it is safe to omit the value until you're ready to configure your environment for a custom editor (in my case, a script).

Answer (score -2):

There is no explicit way to set the variable under knife.rb.
Its good to export on your shell using
$export EDITOR=vim (or any of those that you would like to keep).

Even without setting variable under knife.rf it works. Just export the EDITOR by setting the appropriate value.

Comment: I apologies :(
there is way to set the EDITOR value in knife.rb file and which works perfectly good.